# Sybase iSQL - syntax error near ';' when exporting table to csv

Tags: csv, export, sybase, isql

I'm trying to export a table from a Sybase database to a csv using iSQL and it keeps giving me a syntax error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server 'VSQLSERVER02', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
```

I've tried all of the following and they all give me the same result:

```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL1;
    OUTPUT TO 'W:\\TBL1.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY '|' QUOTE '';
GO
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL1;
    OUTPUT TO 'W:\\TBL1.csv' FORMAT ASCII DELIMITED BY ',' QUOTE '';
GO

    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL1;
    OUTPUT USING 'Driver=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls);
    DBQ=W:\\TBL1.xls;
    READONLY=0' INTO "DATA";
GO
```

If I get rid of the first ; then it tells me there's a syntax error near "OUTPUT". I've looked this error up online and I can't find a solution for it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL02/EBF 27413 SMP/P/AMD64/Windows 2008 R2

Comment: You can't select directly to a file like that with ASE I believe thats SQL Anywhere syntax - you will have to use the BCP tool to export to a csv http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/X14951.htm